# MY AIM IS TO RUN MY EXPO APP ON MY ANDROID EMULATOR LOCALLY

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, expo

### Although when I click on run on android emulator it tries downloading expo go but it doesn't do so successfully. What should I do##[As you can see in the bottom the downloading expo go is running but it doesn't stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhZgv.jpg)

Comment: can you try wiping the device data with [wipe data] and try again

Comment: the error message?